# Accessing functions in a different controller & initializing my masterViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

Technologies: XCode 7.0, Swift 2

Within my `detailViewController` file, I have (among other things):

```
    var masterViewController: MasterViewController? = nil

    @IBAction func saveItem(sender: anyObject) {
            if let newItem = something,
                    let tagItem = newItem
                    self.masterViewController!.model.saveQuery(newItem, forTag: tagItem, syncToCloud: true)
                    let indexPath =
                    NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
                    self.masterViewController!.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath],
                        withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
                    self.masterViewController?.forceSearch(indexPath)
                    self.masterViewController?.tableView.reloadData()
            }

     }
```

So, I'm getting a bad execution error on the `self.masterViewController...saveQuery` line and I think it's related to the fact that my `MasterViewController` is set to `nil`. But, I'm not sure how I should initiate my `MasterViewController` variable or what I should set it too (if that makes sense).

How should I initiate it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of information missing. For example are you using storyboards or not. What's the relation ship between the controllers: are you using a navigation controller or is the detail presented modally for example.

Assuming a navigation controller in a storyboard: there are several ways your detail controller would have knowledge about the master view controller. If you indeed want to use a variable like in your example you could set that before the storyboard segue is performed.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    guard let detailController = segue.destinationController as? DetailViewController else {
        return
    }

    detailController.masterViewController = self
}
```

However in general it's bad practise to have a formal relationship like this. In terms of reusability you are now limiting the detail controller to be presented only by a MasterViewController.

A common pattern used in cases like this would be the delegate pattern. Define a delegate protocol and a delegate property on your detail controller. Set the delegate of the detail controller to the master controller in your `prepareForSegue` for example. And perform any actions to reload the table in the delegate method on the master controller.

Comment: This gives me an error  "'MasterViewController' has no member 'masterViewController'" on the detailController.masterViewController = self line. Also, where should this be placed in my detailViewController; how do I integrate it into my code above? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, the cast should obviously have been to `DetailViewController`. Fixed that in the example. This method should be added to the MasterViewController and will be called before the segue will display your `DetailViewController`.

Comment: @John Kluivers now i get this error from the updated code "Cannot assign a value of type 'DetailViewController' to a value of type 'MasterViewController?'" hmm...

Comment: so that means `self` refers to a `DetailViewController`. You probably added the method to the wrong class. Make sure you add it to your `MasterViewController`

Comment: Thanks - I added it to the MasterViewController. But, in my detailviewcontroller, I originally had this: "var masterViewController: MasterViewController?= nil" and if I remove it, I get errors wherever the MasterViewController call is within my DetailViewController.